# mysql alias subquery used into another subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

how can I get to work the next sentence:

**select 77 as number, (2*number) as mult**

Error: #1054 - Unknown column 'number' in 'field list'

Thanks!

Comment: `select 77 as number, (2*77) as mult`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using alias in subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524781/using-alias-in-subquery)

Comment: Hi, "77" es the result of a long subquery, is what i'm traying to avoid. Thanks